# mysql_connect() system error :111

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 VPS.

I would like to connect from the frist to the second's mysql db like this :

```
$db = mysql_connect("94.xxx.xxx.xxx:222", "user", "pass");
```

I got this  error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading
>   initial communication packet', system error: 111 in
>   /var/www/pcsart/test.php on line 4

My server is works on first server is works on port 222. 
In the first server I don't have a mysql. 
On the second is running on port 3306

First and second server's firewall got these rules :

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:222
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:222
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:222

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:222
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They're deprecated. Look here for alternatives, and that might solve your problem.http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 2):

By default mysql server accept connections only from localhost, to change this behaviour you should change in mysql config the bind-address variable in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
 bind-address=ipAddressOfYourDatabaseServer
```

than restart mysql server.

```
 sudo service mysql restart
```

The explain: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/mysql/switch-mysql-to-listen-on-tcp/

After this i recommend you, that change your iptables, that your 222 port should be reachable only from your other VPS.

```
 iptables -A INPUT -s ! yourOtherVPSipAddress -p tcp -dport 222 -j DROP
```

The other thing: the mysql_ funcrions are deprecated, as the other commenter wrote. If you do not want to make a lot of work with your existing code, you should use mysqli. See the php manual, only a minimal work with sintax if you use mysqli as function library.